# Как использовать 1 case с более чем одной переменной?

Tags: c#

Как использовать 1 case с более чем одной переменной?
в c#

Comment: Приведите пример того, чего вам хочется добиться.

Comment: А зачем?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой способ должен сработать. (не уверен так как, к сожалению, совершенно не знаю C#)

```
String test = "2";
switch(test)
{
      case "1":
      case "2":
          MessageBox.Show("Переменная test равна 1 или 2");
          break;

      default:
          break;
}
```

Немного дополню ответ в связи с новым пониманием вопроса.

В таких случаях можно использовать обычный IF. Например:

```
if(var_one == 1 && var_two == 1) { // do something }
```

Comment: Это пример для одной переменной (в данном случае с именем test). Значния два, а переменная одна.

Comment: а. Вот теперь я понял вопрос... Не уверен что это возможно...

Comment: Да, вопрос явно требует более расширенного описания.

Answer (score 3):

Синтаксис **switch** с несколькими переменными не предусмотрен в C#.

Как описано на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967523/multi-variable-switch-statement-in-c-sharp), более-менее элегантный способ, это использовать кортежи:

```
using System;

static class CompareTuple {
    public static bool Compare<T1, T2, T3>(this Tuple<T1, T2, T3> value, T1 v1, T2 v2, T3 v3) {
        return value.Item1.Equals(v1) && value.Item2.Equals(v2) && value.Item3.Equals(v3); 
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var t = new Tuple<int, int, bool>(1, 2, false);
        if (t.Compare(1, 1, false)) {
            // 1st case
        } else if (t.Compare(1, 2, false)) {
            // 2nd case
        } else { 
            // default
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1 вариант - использовать вложенные case

```
switch(var1)
{
      case 1:
          switch(var2): {
             case 1:
                break;
             case 2:
                break;
          }
          break;

      default:
          break;
}
```

Конечно, вложенные switch лучше вынести в отдельные функции/методы.

2 способ

сгенерировать суррогатный ключ. Например, есть два целочисленных ключа, оба в диапазоне 1-100.

```
varS = var1*100+var2;
switch(varS) {
case 1: // var1 = 0; var2 = 1
   break;
case 204:// var1 = 2; var2 = 4;
   break;
}
```

со строковыми ключами та же история. Просто делаем конкатенацию, желательно разделив каким то уникальным символом (для надежности). Так как может быть два ключа "test1" и "test2" против "test" и "1test2".

Comment: Имхо, второй способ- говнокод (особенно если будет без комментариев).

Comment: все сильно зависит от задачи и от ключей. В большинстве случаев желание сделать switch по двум ключам одновременно уже попахивает плохим дизайном или преждевременной оптимизацией.